# How to get "version code" and "model code" programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How can I get the "model code" in the device's Settings->General->About Screen programmatically?  I also would like to know how to get the "version code" (The alpha-numeric code besides the device's version number).

Comment: @bbarnhart That's not at all what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for, but I wrote this private method the other day for my app.

```
- (NSDictionary*)_getClientDeviceInfo
{
    UIDevice* currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    //version
    NSString* sysVersion = [currentDevice systemVersion];

    //model
    NSString* model = [currentDevice model];

    //platform
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(machine);


    NSDictionary *clientDeviceInfo = @{@"systemVersion":sysVersion, @"model":model, @"platform":platform};

    return clientDeviceInfo;
```

}